# Swift unwind issues, view controllers stack not updated

Tags: swift, unwind-segue

I unwind from controller B to controller A.

When I print my view controllers stack on my unwind function (controller A), I still have my controller B in stack.

Is it normal that after an unwind the controllers stack is not updated ?!

Controller B:

```swift
self.bookmarkViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToViewController", sender: nil)
```

Controller A

```swift
@IBAction func unwindToViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal that after an unwind the controllers stack is not updated
>   ?!

Yes.  At the point that `unwindToViewController` is called, the segue is not yet completed.  For this reason, you can't push a new ViewController from this routine or trigger a new segue.

When `viewDidAppear` runs, the `viewControllers` stack will have been updated.

Comment: Good to know thanks a lot, I thought it was triggered once the segue has been complete...